# Determining extrema of $f(x,y,z)=(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ on $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

> Determine where on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ the function $f(x,y,z)=(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ attains its maximum and minimum.

Using Lagrange multipliers one gets the solutions $(\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$. These are the maximums. However, the system of equations fails to give the minimums, which are attained on the sphere when one of the coordinates is equal to $0$.

My question is whether there is a general method to find ALL the minimums and maximums of a function in several variables in this kind of problem, or if one has to "guess", because clearly Lagrange multipliers don't give all the solutions.

Comment: Lagrange only finds min/max for a function subject to a constraint, and those happen to be abs min/max on that domain. To find relative min/max over the whole domain find the critical points and use the second deriv. Test. Lagrange just gives the absolute min amd max on the constraint. You could look for critical points of the function that are on the sphere, if any.

Comment: But I already found all the critical points. The minimum isn't attained at critical points.

Comment: Well two of the coordinates would have to be zero to be on the sphere. That's strange are you sure (0,0,1), (1,0,0), (0,1,0) were not solutions? If you divide you can lose zero.

Comment: Oh, you mean the critical points on the sphere? Well, yeah, those are the solutions, yeah. OK, thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. If when creating the lagrange equations and solving you divide by x, y or z, you will lose the 0 coordinate solution. Like $(0,\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}} ,\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}}) $ and its permutations and negatives, or the other I gave above. I don't know if this or the others are solutions,  since I haven't solved it. But lagrange will give the abs minimums. Since coordinates with 0 components are on the sphere, f=0 SEEMS to be both a abs min on the domain and the sphere domain. It seems like you lost zero some where.

Comment: But with lagrange you should have no use of critical points unless you need something inside the sphere.

Comment: The reason Lagrange multipliers don't give the minima is that $f$ is not differentiable there.